# How to Make PHPStorm / Intellij IDEA Dark (Whole IDE, not just color scheme)

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I've just downloaded the new PHPStorm EAP, and noticed this screenshot:

[image: PHPStorm Dark]

And I like it very much. Thing is, I can't find any option to make my install looks like this. I know about color scheme, but AFAIK it only change the text editor's color. How can I make my install to look like that? (The screenshot is taken from [the EAP site](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/Web+IDE+EAP)).

Comment: Pro programmers use dark IDEs. :)

Answer (score 144, accepted):

**Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Appearance | Theme = Darcula**

**P.S.**
Since IntelliJ IDEA v14 / WebStorm v9 / PhpStorm v8.0.2 (and any other IDEs on branch 139.xxx or newer) the settings path is a bit different:

**Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Appearance & Behaviour | Appearance | Theme = Darcula**

[image]

Comment: This option is gone in WebStorm 7 EAP (but may come back later on official release?). The answer below works in EAP though.

Comment: @WilsonHaw Nope -- it is still there (checked in PhpStorm though, build 130.1481): http://postimg.org/image/fla5w2d49/

Answer (score 49):

> View -> Quick Switch Theme -> Switch Look And Feel -> Darcula

and `Restart the IDEA` if changes do not become apparent.

Comment: On PHPStorm 8.0.2 Mac the 'Switch Look and Feel' can be done without a restart. ;)

Comment: IT's actually called darcula, not dracula

Comment: There are only two options?

Answer (score 12):

Download and enable [ColorIDE](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7055?pr=clion).

> Preferences > Plugins > "Browse repositories..." button > search for "ColorIde"

Instead of being limited to the standard 4 themes that come with the IDE, ColorIDE plugin will give your IDE the same look and feel as your current color scheme.

Comment: Been wanting this forever, didn't know it even existed.  Thank you.

Comment: Nice.  I also just discovered that if you want your code background to be different from the tree background, you can control the latter with this plugin by setting the Editor->Colors & Fonts->General->Text->Default Text (which may require a restart to take effect), and change your code background color on a per-language basis.

Answer (score 6):

### Use Material UI

If `Darcula` isn't darker enough, you can use a plugin called Material UI.

[image: A screenshot of Material UI]

They also have many other colors like deep blue, marine blue, etc.

[Link to Material Theme UI](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006-material-theme-ui)

Answer (score 4):

On Mac the title bar of every window (both main and popup dialoges) will remain the typical Mac grayish color, even using the Darcula theme. But you can actually make it dark as well.

Using any Jetbrain IDE (including DataGrip), press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (PC) or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (Mac). This will open the command palette where you can find *Registry*:

[image]

Open the registry and find the key *ide.mac.allowDarkDindowDecorations*:

[image]

Enable this, close the registry and restart the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

In `Preferences > Editor > Colors & Fonts`, pick a dark scheme and the IDE will ask you if you want to switch the whole IDE to a dark scheme:

[image: dialog]