# In phpstorm, how do I switch back to default color theme look and feel?

Tags: colors, themes

I have set my phpstorm color scheme to dark theme - "Darcula" theme.

There was a pop up asking if I would also like to change my default look and feel to dark, I clicked on yes, but now I cannot switch back to regular look and feel!

Although the editor background changes according to the scheme, all the other window backgrounds stay dark!

Comment: Same as here, just other way arround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504594/how-to-make-phpstorm-intellij-idea-dark-whole-ide-not-just-color-scheme

Comment: Thanks it worked (the second answer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Make PHPStorm / Intellij IDEA Dark (Whole IDE, not just color scheme)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504594/how-to-make-phpstorm-intellij-idea-dark-whole-ide-not-just-color-scheme)

Answer (score 65):

```
File -> Settings -> Apperarance - Theme.
```

Then u can change it to whatever you want to again.

```
File -> Settings -> Colors & Fonts Scheme name.
```

This will change your editor themes and color.

Answer (score 33):

You can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> (tild - switch below the ESC switch the tild) and select look and feel.
From the same <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> you can choose the key map and more things in phpstorm.

Comment: You're an angel time travelling from 3 years in the past.  Thank you.  Has been helpful more than you know.

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to switch to other color scheme in `/settings/appearance/`, it always reverted to dark theme. Disabling Material Theme UI plugin in  `/settings/plugins/` helped. Now I can switch between any themes.

Answer (score 2):

You can Switch Many ways..

1. by press `Ctrl` + `~`
2. open action window by press **`Ctrl`** + **`Shift`** + **`A`** 
   and type `Theme` showing all the themes which you have installed in phpstrom

Answer (score 1):

For Window10:  File -> Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme

Comment: Same for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your phpstrom setting.
2. Click on Editor option.
3. After Editor you click on Colors Scheme.
4. Select the Scheme option and click on apply button.