# Change debug window style in phpstorm

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I want to change color scheme in debug variable window. Can someone help where can I change debug variable style in phpstorm? I try to find by path `settings -> color & fonts -> debugger` but without success.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So ... what elements you want to change? Because all what I see now is empty debug window...

Comment: My bed. I have updated the image. You can see there red variables. So color of these variables I want to change.

Comment: From what I see you are using **dark editor color scheme** (possibly Darcula) **with light GUI theme**. I believe that this color is part of the GUI theme and cannot be customized as color remains the same regardless of editor color scheme). My only suggestion is to switch whole IDE to use dark scheme -- the color for that element will be much more appropriate/suitable (light rose? -- http://postimg.org/image/wg1nhp19h/) -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/13505114/783119

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see you are using **dark editor color scheme** (possibly Darcula) together **with light GUI theme**.

You can change colors for numbers/strings .. but not for variable names -- it seems to be part of the GUI Theme itself as it does not change together with editor color scheme.

My only suggestion is to switch whole IDE to use dark GUI scheme -- the color for that element will be much more appropriate/suitable (light rose?):
[image]

It can be changed at **Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Appearance | UI Options | Theme | Darcula** (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13505114/783119 for details)