# Reset default settings in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, user-preferences

I have applied [this theme](https://github.com/ChrisRM/material-theme-jetbrains) to WebStorm, but I do not like it.

How can I revert to WebStorm's default setting?

Comment: I tend to delete the **.idea** folder from the project directory for a clean reset. Be warned, this will remove any preferences you have set up.

Comment: @camden_kid It will not help here as this is an IDE-wide setting and not project-specific.

Answer (score 18):

Depending on what OS you are on, you should be able to remove the config file and WebStorm will recreate it.

Normally, there are `.idea` folders as @camden_kid said.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/project-and-ide-settings.html

#### Windows

```
<User home>\.WebStormXX\config that contains user-specific settings.

<User home> in WindowsXP is C:\Documents and Settings\<User name>\;
in Windows Vista it is C:\Users\<User name>\
```

#### Linux

```
/.WebStormXX/config that contains user-specific settings
```

#### Mac

```
~/Library/Preferences/WebStormXX contains the rest of the configuration settings.
```

You might be able to just swap theme depending on how destructive the theme files were.

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/appearance.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13505114/878344

Comment: You may want to backup the deleted folder before deleting it. Exporting the settings should also help.

Comment: Why would you backup an auto generated file you are trying to reset?

Comment: If you don't know a backup is not needed. If the solution works, you can just delete the backup. If it doesn't, you can perhaps recover other valuable settings  and try a different solution.

Comment: I mean thats not the purpose of a "reset" by definition but I understand your logic..

Answer (score 12):

Just disable (or better -- uninstall) that plugin -- that's it.

1. `Settings/Preferences | Plugins`
2. Find that plugin (`Material Theme UI`) and click "Uninstall"
3. Close Settings/Preferences window by clicking `OK` button
4. Restart IDE
5. Now you can change GUI Theme and Editor Color Schema separately

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling the previous used Material UI Theme plugin didn't help completely for me, because some colors were still overwritten.

After deleting the "colors" folder inside the config folder of my WebStorm installation directory, the default theme was reset completely.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS Mojave, I had to go to

```
/Users/loggedInUser/Library/preferences/WebStorm2019.2/
```

and delete the `colors` and `options` folders. That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Directories used by the IDE to store settings, caches, plugins and logs:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Answer (score 0):

To reset to default settings, first close webstorm and delete configurations e.g:

```
$ rm -rf ~/.config/JetBrains/WebStorm2021.3/
```

Then start webstorm again.